# Java sorted and iterable Defaultlistmodel

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I'm trying to extend the DefaultListModel so it will be sort-able and iterable. I found some code here http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t94074.html. I'm now trying to parameterize this code, but the addAll,containsAll,removeAll,retainAll, and toArray methods all give a name clash error. I kind of understand why this is, but I'm unsure how to fix it. Is there a better way to do this? Code below

```
package main;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DefaultListModelSort<E extends Object> extends DefaultListModel<E>
        implements List<E> {
    private Delegate m_delegate = new Delegate();

    public DefaultListModelSort() {
        super();
    }

    public DefaultListModelSort(Collection<E> c) {
        this();
        addAll(c);
    }

    public boolean add(E o) {
        return m_delegate.add(o);
    }

    public boolean removeE(E o) {
        return m_delegate.remove(o);
    }

    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<E> c) {
        return m_delegate.addAll(index, c);
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<E> c) {
        return m_delegate.addAll(c);
    }

    public boolean containsAll(Collection<E> c) {
        return m_delegate.containsAll(c);
    }

    public boolean removeAll(Collection<E> c) {
        return m_delegate.removeAll(c);
    }

    public boolean retainAll(Collection<E> c) {
        return m_delegate.retainAll(c);
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return m_delegate.iterator();
    }

    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return m_delegate.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        return m_delegate.listIterator();
    }

    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
        return m_delegate.listIterator(index);
    }

    public E[] toArray(E a[]) {
        return m_delegate.toArray(a);
    }

    /**
     * This class extends AbstractList so we get all the functionality of
     * iterators and such for free.
     */
    private class Delegate extends AbstractList<E> {

        public Delegate() {
            super();
        }

        public E get(int index) {
            return DefaultListModelSort.super.get(index);
        }

        public int size() {
            return DefaultListModelSort.super.size();
        }

        public E set(int index, E element) {
            return DefaultListModelSort.super.set(index, element);
        }

        public void add(int index, E element) {
            DefaultListModelSort.super.add(index, element);
        }

        public E remove(int index) {
            return DefaultListModelSort.super.remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to extend the DefaultListModel so it will be sort-able and
>   iterable.

- use [JTable with one Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), `JTableHeader` can be removed
- for more info about `RowSorter` to read Oracle tutorial [How to use Tables - Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)